# How do i fix skype desktop installer returning 1603 on windows 8

Tags: windows-8, skype

I run into this issue sometimes and always end up on a google search spelunking trip until I find whatever workaround forces skype to install this time.

So how do I fix skype installer failing with error 1603?

Answer (score 6):

Error **1603** is a generic error message return from the msi-installer. The easiest fix is running the msi directly from here:
http://www.skype.com/go/getskype-msi

If that doesn't work you can supposedly use [lessmsi](https://code.google.com/p/lessmsi/downloads/list) and unpack the skype.exe (from the msi-file downloaded in the last section) which should be able to bootstrap on it's own. Put it somewhere you'd like skype installed and start skype.exe

Comment: http://superuser.com/search?q=install+1603

Comment: Probably the most useless comment ever. Yes I have searched. No it doesnt turn up anything useful.

Comment: It's to point out that, as you say in this answer, 1603 is a very generic error -- not to suggest it's leading to a specific fix.

Answer (score 1):

This can be resolved by renaming the Skype folder in AppData\Roaming:

1. Windows Key + R > CMD
2. `rename "%appdata%\Skype" "Skype_"`
3. Run Skype Installer

Confirmed on Win10 1607 with Skype 7.33.105.

Answer (score 0):

I found that simply trying to uninstall Skype did not fix this error, because the error dictates that it cannot remove the old version of Skype.

After much searching I found a fix and posted the information [here to my blog.](http://www.lauramartin.co.nz/skype-error-code-1603-a-fatal-error-occurred-during-installation/)
Basically I would suggest running through the steps suggested here. I am certain you will find a solution here.

> If you are receiving the error above, this is probably not going to work for you. Because this error states it cannot uninstall app.
>
> - Start > Control Panel > Uninstall Programs
> - Choose the program if you can find it.
> - Uninstall.
> - Remove registry files for Skype
>
> Always exercise extreme caution when working with registry keys. You can do major damage here! I just exporting and backing up before any change you make.
>
> - Start > Search > Type regedit
> - Open HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.
> - Open SOFTWARE.
> - Find Skype.
> - Backup files by rigth click and exporting them to another location.
> - Delete the Skype folder.
>
> #### Try using the Microsoft Automated Fix
>
> - Go to http://support2.microsoft.com/mats/program_install_and_uninstall/ and
>   click the big Fix Now Button.
> - Follow the directions and choose the program you are having trouble with, which in this case will be Skype.
> - This method was successful for me.
>
> #### Uninstall Security Update KB2918614
>
> This Update is known to cause errors in msi (install files)
>
> - Start > Search > WIndows Updates
> - Search for “KB2918614″, if the update is installated try uninstalling it.

The third step worked a gem for me and I was able to install Skype successfully after.

Comment: Although your answers have been relevant, most or all of them are promotional in nature. This is likely to result in [your account being suspended](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/). If you'd like to promote your own products, please consider [purchasing ads on Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/about/contact). See also the [help/behavior] and http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2352.

Comment: Note: Account was suspended for 7 days starting from 2015-01-05 at 21:53 UTC for a spam post.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be related to the Program Files (x86) directory.  It still wouldn't install in the default location, so I changed it to C:/Skype and it installed correctly.